# Add annotation to UIImageView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiimageview, mkannotation

You find ton of examples/libraries of how to add annotations on a mapView.
But I was wondering if there are any libraries to add annotations to an UIImageView.

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0):

you can try this for buttons and views https://github.com/malcommac/CMPopTipView it works like a charm! (this code is for a button but it's the same for an uimageview with `UIGestureRecognizer`)

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, SwiftPopTipViewDelegate {
var roundRectButtonPopTipView: SwiftPopTipView?

@IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    // Toggle popTipView when a standard UIButton is pressed
    if let _ = roundRectButtonPopTipView {
        // Dismiss
        roundRectButtonPopTipView?.dismissAnimated(true)
        roundRectButtonPopTipView = nil
    } else {
        roundRectButtonPopTipView = SwiftPopTipView(message: "My message")
        roundRectButtonPopTipView?.delegate = self
        roundRectButtonPopTipView?.popColor = UIColor.lightGray
        roundRectButtonPopTipView?.textColor = UIColor.darkText

        roundRectButtonPopTipView?.presentPointingAtView(sender as! UIView, containerView: view, animated: true)
    }
}

//MARK: - SwiftPopTipViewDelegate methods
func popTipViewWasDismissedByUser(popTipView: SwiftPopTipView) {
    // User can tap SwiftPopTipView to dismiss it
    roundRectButtonPopTipView = nil
}
}
```